# DSolve fails to find solution based on elementary function

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, trigonometry

I have two differential equations for which `DSolve` does not find a solution, however, there are simple solutions in terms of elementary functions, and more specifically hyperbolic trigonometric functions.

I am using

```
$Version
"12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"
```

Then I run:

```
DSolve[{r[σ]^2 + 
  Derivative[1][r][σ]^2 - 
    Derivative[1][y][σ]^2 + 
      y[σ]*Derivative[2][y][σ] == 0, 
  r[σ]*y[σ] + 2*Derivative[1][r][σ] * Derivative[1][y][σ] - 
    y[σ]*Derivative[2][r][σ] == 0}, 
  {y[σ], r[σ]}, σ]
```

which does not return any solutions.

Even if I add conditions

```
DSolve[{r[σ]^2 + Derivative[1][r][σ]^2 - Derivative[1][y][σ]^2 + y[σ]*Derivative[2][y][σ] == 0, 
   r[σ]*y[σ] + 2*Derivative[1][r][σ]*Derivative[1][y][σ] - y[σ]*Derivative[2][r][σ] == 0, 
  y[0] == 0, 
  y[Infinity] == 1, 
  r[0] == 1, 
  r[Infinity] == 0}, {y[σ], r[σ]}, σ]
```

it just returns the input of DSolve as output.

However, simple and elementary solutions exist as the following expressions yield zero

```
FullSimplify[r[σ]^2 + Derivative[1][r][σ]^2 - Derivative[1][y][σ]^2 + y[σ]*Derivative[2][y][σ] /. 
    y -> (Tanh[#1] & ) /. r -> (1/Cosh[#1] & )]
FullSimplify[r[σ]*y[σ] + 2*Derivative[1][r][σ]*Derivative[1][y][σ] - y[σ]*Derivative[2][r][σ] /. 
    y -> (Tanh[#1] & ) /. r -> (1/Cosh[#1] & )]
```

Any ideas on how to approach `DSolve` to obtain the two solutions I know exist?

Comment: `Any ideas on how to approach DSolve to obtain the two solutions` with `DSolve` there is really not much tweaking one can do from the outside to help it find a solution. It  either finds a solution or it can't. This is different from `NDSolve` where one can adjust many parameters to help it. `DSolve` just can't solve this. May be in the next version 13 it can.

Comment: Please report this to "support@wolfram.com" and post their answer here. It would be interesting to know the reason.

Comment: @DanielHuber will do and update

Comment: (1) It's a nonlinear second-order system: hardly simple. (2) The equation is singular at $y=0$, that is, at $\sigma=0$ for the solution exhibited. Again, not simple. (3) I don't believe `DSolve` will work with boundary conditions at `Infinity`. (4) The existence of a simple closed-form particular solution does not mean the general solution is simple or even closed-form. (5) When the general solution cannot be found, finding particular solutions in closed-form strikes me as a rather hard problem. — Is there reason to doubt the implicit assumptions in these comments for this ODE system?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a workaround to obtain simpler solutions.  You have coupled odes with `y` and `r` as dependent variables.

```
ode1 = r[σ]^2 + r'[σ]^2 - y'[σ]^2 + y[σ]*y''[σ] == 0
ode2 = r[σ]*y[σ] + 2*r'[σ]*y'[σ] - y[σ]*r''[σ] == 0
```

Solve `ode2` for `y`. This works. This is the only startup that worked. Now replace `ode1` by this solution. This gives an new ode just in `r`. This will have one constant of integration in it. Now the only way to continue is for the special case of this constant zero. This simplifies the new ode, which now `DSolve` can solve for `r`.  Substitute these solutions back in `ode2`. This gives a new ode in `y` which `DSolve` can now solve.  This gives these two solutions

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are verified and valid solutions, and agree with Maple also which can solve this system. There are many other solutions, since the above solution are when that constant of integration was set to 0.

Here is the code

```
Clear["Global`*"]
ode1 = r[σ]^2 + r'[σ]^2 - y'[σ]^2 + y[σ]*y''[σ] == 0
ode2 = r[σ]*y[σ] + 2*r'[σ]*y'[σ] - y[σ]*r''[σ] == 0
solY = DSolve[ode2, y, σ][[1, 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 ode1A = ode1 /. solY /. C[1] -> 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 solR = Flatten@DSolve[ode1A, r, σ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 ode2A = (ode2 /. #) & /@ solR
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 solY = Flatten[DSolve[#, y, σ] & /@ ode2A]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Verify**

```
 ode1 /. {solY[[1]], solR[[1]]}
 ode2 /. {solY[[1]], solR[[1]]}
 ode1 /. {solY[[2]], solR[[2]]}
 ode2 /. {solY[[2]], solR[[2]]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Again, this is not the complete set of solutions. There are more. Also note that these solution can be considered as particular solutions and not general general, since one of the constant of integration was set to zero to obtain them. In a general solution, there will be two arbitrary constants for each dependent variable.

Also note that `y=0` and `r=0` are also solutions

```
ode1 /. {r -> Function[{σ}, 0], y -> Function[{σ}, 0]}
ode2 /. {r -> Function[{σ}, 0], y -> Function[{σ}, 0]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]